# Spring : Cannot get value from application.properties

Tags: java, spring, application.properties

I created Spring project via Spring Initializr with project following struct:

[image]

I defined property in application.properties file :

```
my.prop=testvalue
```

I inject this value into MyClass as following :

```
@Component
class MyClass {

    @Value("${my.prop}")
    private String myProp;

    public String getMyProp() {
        return myProp;
    }
}
```

ConfigBeans defined as following:

```
package com.example.propertiesdemo;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class ConfigBeans {
    @Bean
    public MyClass myLitoBean() {
        return new MyClass();
    }
}
```

PropertiesdemoApplication.java :

```
package com.example.propertiesdemo;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;

@SpringBootApplication
public class PropertiesdemoApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ApplicationContext context
                = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(
                        ConfigBeans.class);
        MyClass myClass = context.getBean(MyClass.class);
        System.out.println(myClass.getMyProp());
    }
}
```

I am expecting that after executing line
System.out.println(myClass.getMyProp());
will be printed value of myprop defined in application.properties (i.e testvalue), but after running (via Netbeans IDE) I get output :

```
${my.prop}
```

What was missed / wromg in this code ? Thanks in advance

Comment: You can check this https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/PropertySource.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You dont need to create an application context in the main method like this. The presented code is a kind of mixture of "traditional" spring and spring boot. So you're kind of bypassing all the goodies that spring boot offers, among which is automatic `application.properties` loading.

If you're using spring boot (there is a `@SpringBootApplication` annotation) then it will create everything by itself.

Usually it should be something like this

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(PropertiesdemoApplication.class, args);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks , After change it works - it was my mistake

Answer (score 5):

You are creating `MyClass` bean twice.

1. Using `@component` annotation
2. using `@bean` annotation in the config class (use method name lowerCamelCase i.e. in your case `myClass()`)

Create bean only once using any one of the above.

Comment: Thanks . Removed extra Bean creation  . Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Right, as Navnath Adsul said, you need the bean to be created once, and also, since you are using Spring Boot, you need to raise the context using a special method

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class PropertiesdemoApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    // Inject Bean
    @Autowired
    private MyClass myClass;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SpringApplicationBuilder()
                .sources(PropertiesdemoApplication.class)
                .run(args);
       // or SpringApplication.run(PropertiesdemoApplication.class, args);

    }

    @Override
    public void run(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(myClass.getMyProp());                    
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class PropertiesdemoApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(PropertiesdemoApplication.class, args);
        MyClass myClass = context.getBean(MyClass.class);
        System.out.println(myClass.getMyProp());
    }
}
```